# Counting distinct elements and their frequency short method using collections.Counter()

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, collections, counter

Input-

The first line contains the integer n.
The next n lines each contain a word.

```
4
abc
abcdef
abcd
abc
```

Output-

Output 2 lines.
On the first line, output the number of distinct words from the input.
On the second line, output the number of occurrences for each distinct word according to their appearance in the input.

```
3
2 1 1
```

Here is my code-

```
import collections
n=int(input())
l=[]
l1=[]
for i in range(n):
    st=input()
    l1.append(st)
    if st not in l:
     l.append(st)
frequency = collections.Counter(l1)
d=dict(frequency)
print(len(l))
for i in d.values():
  print(i,end=" ")
```

Is there any shorter way by which I can do this, using a single list instead of creating two (l and l2).

Comment: @DanielHao ya sure I would like to prefer.

Comment: I see the answer being accepted, so I will pass then.

Comment: @DanielHao No No actually I didn't.

Comment: I woul like to do it by using collections.Counter() specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this sample and modify it to suit your requirement to get your desired output. It used only ONE list, instead of two.  However, I *leave a step out* **on purpose**, so that you can refine it and practice.  Just try to type the same sample inputs and see what's the output.

```
from collections import Counter

N  =  int(input('Number of words: (one per line)'))  # how many numbers of words, eg. 5

l1  =  []

#for i in range(N):
ll = [input() for _ in range(N) ]  # get all words, one per line
      
#frequency =  Counter(l1)

counts = Counter(ll)

for v in counts.values():
  print(v,   end=" ")
```

Comment: Yes I got it. Further I converted the list l1 to set to get the number of distinct elements

Comment: You could play the code changes via this great visual platform too -http://www.pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit shorter and only 1 dictionary instead of 2 lists

```
n=int(input())
d = {}
for _ in range(n):
    l = input()
    if l in d:
        d[l] += 1
    else:
        d[l] = 1
print(len(d))
for a in d:
    print(d[a], end=" ")
```

Comment: can there be any other way using collections.Counter() function?

Comment: @sam2611 - see the latest Post, any questions - please ask.